# Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist -> [Help 1]

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, jhipster, liquibase

Just update Jhispter "jhipsterVersion": "6.3.0", 
and this:

```
./mvnw liquibase:diff
```

**gives error:** 
Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist -> [Help 1].

**pom.xml**

```
<changeLogFile>
 ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
</changeLogFile>
<diffChangeLogFile>        
${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml
</diffChangeLogFile> 


 <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.gotop.nms.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
```

Any idea what can I change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug of the Hibernate Liquibase Maven plugin, if you change the version of the library from:

```
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.7</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
```

to:

```
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
```

and executes again

```
./mvnw liquibase:diff
```

it should work

Check out [this comment](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/170#issuecomment-527869840) of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Amau Garcia I can see jhipster fix here https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10435/files